# Custom TypeConverter that receives a few objects and converts them to another object

Tags: micronaut

I'd like to create a custom `TypeConverter` that receives a few objects and converts them to another object.
E.g. to convert `(MyEntity, AdditionalEntity, locale)` to `MyDto`.

Is there any way to pass a few objects to a `TypeConverter` except creating a DTO `(MyEntity, AdditionalEntity, locale)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the conversion service only accepts a single object